# flask calling a function from another

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am   calling   a function   from another   fuction.

The  function   I am calling

```
@app.route('/csv/')  
def download_csv(p): 
    csv = p
    response = make_response(csv)
    cd = 'attachment; filename=RosterUnified.csv'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = cd 
    response.mimetype='text/csv'
    return response
```

In my  HTML    this   is   associated with a  button click 'Download'.

I am calling this from within:

```
@app.before_request
def ros_before_app():
   . 
   .
   .





    z=open(Filename1)
    with z as f:
        p = f.read()
        download_csv(p) 

    z.close()
    else:
      z1=open(Filename)
      with z1 as f1:
        p = f1.read()
        download_csv(p)
```

The   console   gives  the  error:

```
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: download_csv() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'
```

and  the  'Download' button on click  gives download failed, server  problem

Comment: if you use `p` as parameter in download_csv function, it must be in the route. In this example, you cannot put a function in url(only string or int works). You have to import the p function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flask the `@app.route('/')` decorator must contain any arguments that are passed into the function. You can do this by adding a `<var>` tag to the url. So the code you have might look like this,

```
@app.route('/csv/<p>')
def download_csv(p):
  csv = p
  # continue code here...
```

Variable, `csv` equals `file` if the URL is `.../csv/file`. Notice how instead of saying `<p>` we put in an argument that got passed into the function.

For even more infromation on variable passing in this decorator, look at [Flask's Variable Rules](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#variable-rules).

Comment: thanks,  now   I   get download failed  with below  error in console,what does   this mean

Comment: []
[]
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2016 13:05:43] "GET /csv/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Well, a 404 error is something is not found or is non-existent. The 127.0.0.1 is local host. I think what this is saying is that it can't get the file "/csv/HTTP/1.1" on localhost; however, I'm not too good at web development started a few years ago.